# how to catch the event of shutting down of tomcat?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

What I want is to start a thread every time the tomcat server starts.For this I need to catch the event of shutting down of tomcat.How can I do this?I tried to do it using sessions but sometimes the session even persists after shutting down and restating tomcat?what are my options?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: If you want to do something *on startup*, why are you looking for *shutdown* events? That doesn't make sense to me. This seems like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: *sometimes the session even persists* I don't think so. How are you validating it?

Comment: You can't get tomcat shutdown process, but you can get the process when your web application is being undeployed or shut down using `ServletContextListener`.

Comment: What I am trying to do is run a thread through a jsp page on startup..but I don't want multiple instance of that thread everytime the jsp page is visited.for that I thought the best solution would be to run the thread only when the tomcat starts ..if I know that tomcat has been shutdown and started again then I have to start the thread..that's why the question..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try to catch an JVM shutdown event in this way:

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("BYE BYE");
        }
    });
```

The other option is to implement ServletContextListener by using **@WebListener** Annotation. No xml configuration is required in this case.

```
@WebListener
public class MyLifeCycleListener implements ServletContextListener {

      public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
          //TODO ON START
      }

      public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
          //TODO ON DESTROY
      }
}
```