# How to add listener in spring batch job to catch tomcat shut down event

Tags: tomcat, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

My spring batch job is running on tomcat, it hangs. I tried to shut the tomcat down and start it up again, it still shows the job is running with a status STARTED.

I need to add a listener in the batch job, it should catch the event of shutting down tomcat, then kill the threads of the batch job.

Any idea to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You may would like to refer to the following question [catching the event of shutting down tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24784508/how-to-catch-the-event-of-shutting-down-of-tomcat)

You can then make that class listen to the batch job events.