# How do I stop the thread when tomcat stop

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

java code

```
static ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 10, 0l, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());

threadPoolExecutor.execute(customer);

class Customer implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

tomcat stop but thread is still alive;
How do I stop the thread when tomcat stop?

Comment: Call the ThreadPool.[shutdownNow()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdownNow()) method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call shutdownNow on the executor service in a servletcontextlistener on contextDestroyed, that will interrupt the threads in the pool. See this question:
[how to catch the event of shutting down of tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24784508/217324)

But your Customer Runnable doesn't stop what it's doing in response to interruption, so shutting the threadpool down won't cause it to quit. Change the Customer's run method to exit the loop when it detects the interrupt flag:

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

.